# Android secure communications: JSSE or Apache Http?

Tags: android

After having all kinds of problems taking my functioning JSSE-based HttpsURLConnection implementation using a custom truststore on Windows to Android I have come across a number of issues that I cannot get answers to: (the Android app still does not work)

1. Does Android 4.0 still only support the BKS format for keystores and truststores (and not JKS)? My Windows application used JKS.
2. Is JSSE or ApacheHttp better to use for secure TLS communications on the Android platform? (My Windows application used JSSE HttpsURLConnection and friends)

Before I start struggling with getting custom truststores working on Android I would like to know if using JSSE is barking up the wrong tree. Surely there must be a reason for having both of these APIs available!  Then again, maybe not.

Comment: This sums nicely differences: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android system trust store has been extended in ICS, and now lets you install trusted certificates. After you do, they will be picked up by the default `TrustManager` and both `HttpClient` and `HttpsUrlConnection` should just work, no need for a custom store. More details [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/ics-trust-store-implementation.html). The JKS format is proprietary, and is most likely not supported.

Apache HttpClient is more flexible and has more expressive API, but the Android team has stated that they will only improve `HttpConnection` from now on. So, for newer platforms, that should probably be your choice if you can bear with the API. BTW, on Android, both are using the same JSSE implementation based on native OpenSSL code. Certificate verification is, however, done in Java and is largely based on the BouncyCastle code.

Update: some sample code on how to do this with both HttpClient and HttpsURLConnection:

https://github.com/nelenkov/custom-cert-https

Related blog post:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: This is a great article; I had no idea the truststore implementation on Android was so crippled. With the great improvement supplied by ICS it still does not sound possible to do either of the following:
1. Create an application truststore to be used only by the application (which is possible in JSSE Java implementations) [the application is interested in secure communications with only a limited set of servers, in this case WAN receivers for health data]
2. Have the application (apk) add certificates to the mutable truststore. These might include self-signed certificates.

Comment: Though the article is great, I have to admit I am disappointed in the lack of flexibility of the Android JSSE.

Comment: 1. was possible even before 4.0: just create a BKS keystore, and initialize your socket factory with it (that was the only way to use custom CA certificates before ICS). 2. is possible in ICS using the new KeyStore API like this: `Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, cert);
startActivity(intent);` The user must of course authorize this. (there is an article about this too, including some sample code on github).

Comment: Okay; I guess I need to do more work. On Windows (straight Java) all I had to do was set a property to use a custom truststore. I could still use default truststore and keystore managers. Clearly this is not possible on Android (even this systemProps.put("javax.net.debug", "SSL"); doesn't work on Android!)

Comment: I am going to read the rest of all the security related articles. I've been googling for days to get this info and could not find it. There's lots of confusion out there! Your articles are a life-saver. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, `javax.net.debug` is indeed sorely missed :) BTW, the trust store /key store system properties are referenced in the source, and Android does set the trust store one to the location of the system trust store (cacerts.bks). It should be technically be possible to use them for user applications, but I haven't heard of anyone succeeding, and I haven't looked into it in detail.

Comment: Okay I still have no success: since System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", file) does not work

Comment: Okay I still have no success: since System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", file) does not work I do the following (sorry about the inability to format): 1. place BKS truststore in /res/raw: contains server certificate.   2. Load truststore into internal memory if not already there.  3. Create KeyStore of BKS type.   4. Load the truststore into KeyStore object.  5. Get default SSLSocketFactory  6. Get instance of TrustManagerFactory with default algorithm  7. Initialize the TrustManagerFactory with the KeyStore object 8. Get the SSL context for TLSv1.

Comment: 9. Initialize the SSLContext with TrustManagers from the above TrustManagerFactory.  10. Still get error Trust anchor for certification path not found  --- This is the MOST bizarre system I have ever worked with!!!

Comment: Sounds about right, but don't have time check right now. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) class makes it easier and [here](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html) is a good write up about using certificates (with httpclient).

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that. I am going the HttpsURLConnection approach after reading the article you pointed to. I'm probably missing something very simple. If only System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", file) worked like it does in real JSSE java!

Comment: You probably have it figured by now, but see sample project and blog post I linked in the answer. Conclusion: it works :)